# Bolding expression in latex

Tags: latex

I want to bold the expression as these are vectors but instead i am getting weird results.As i have comfortable on writing equation with equation command would love changes in the given code.

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    \implies \textbf{\frac{dL}{dt}=\sum_{i} r_{i} \times F_{i}^{ext}=N^{ext}}=\text{Sum of external torques}
    \end{equation*}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `textbf` you're swapping back to text mode, and as such you need to surround any maths syntax with `$`'s. As such, the following would work:

```
\begin{equation*}
    \implies \textbf{$\frac{dL}{dt}=\sum_{i} r_{i} \times F_{i}^{ext}=N^{ext}$}=\text{Sum of external torques}
\end{equation*}
```

Having said this, given that you want to remain in math mode, it's easier to just use `\mathbf` and forget about the `$`'s:

```
\begin{equation*}
    \implies \mathbf{\frac{dL}{dt}=\sum_{i} r_{i} \times F_{i}^{ext}=N^{ext}}=\text{Sum of external torques}
\end{equation*}
```

Even with this, I tend to prefer using the `bm` package for bolding maths. [Although there are loads of different ways to bold math fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/181010).

Comment: will \bf always work or it may fail too.And what to prefer \bf or \bm?

Comment: Two letter font switches like `\bf` are obsolete and should no longer be used

Comment: can you explain with an example i didn't understand?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks, I did not know this. I shall update the answer to reflect this. (Although it should be noted that `\bm` could also be interpreted as a "two letter font switch", though as far as I'm aware this is not considered obsolete)

Comment: @Ralph `\bm` is not defined by tex, but comes from the boldmath package which isn't obsolete

Comment: @Ralph  can you help me on this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61498401/huge-spacing-between-text/61510101#61510101