# Huge Spacing between text

Tags: latex

In the given latex code below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*} N_{i}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{i} \times F_{i}^{j}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{j} \times F_{i}^{j} \text{()used dummy varialble concept} \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

i want spacing between the equation and the text part on right hand side in the given code (as we normally see in any physics book) as am i comfortable on working them and also if the text on right side is more in text i want it to go just below of it and then to start writing other things normally.

Comment: @Ralph can you help on this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds that you might be looking for the `\tag` command? This will push your text to the right-most position on the page.

```
\begin{equation*}
    N_{i}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{i} \times F_{i}^{j}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{j} \times F_{i}^{j} \tag*{()used dummy variable concept}
\end{equation*}
```

The `flalign` enviornment can be used to get a similar result:

```
\begin{flalign*}
   &&N_{i}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{i} \times F_{i}^{j}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{j} \times F_{i}^{j} && \text{()used dummy varialble concept}
\end{flalign*}
```

I'm sure there are lots of other ways to get at what you desire, but it seems that `\tag` might be closest to what you're looking for.

Comment: can it go more further to right and also i want some text to be atmost right and in case the text goes to new line i want it to start with the atmost right below the atmost text i am writing

Answer (score 1):

If you want spacing between the equation you can use different spacing commands such as:

1. \; - a thick space.
2. : - a medium space.
3. \, - a thin space.
4. ! - a negative thin space.

Here is the code for spacing.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*} 
N_{i}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{i} \times F_{i}^{j}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{j} \times F_{i}^{j \; \; \; \; } \text{()used dummy varialble concept} 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

If you want to add a linebreak between the equation and the text, then you can use `\begin{split}` and `\end{split}`

For example:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{split} 
N_{i}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{i} \times F_{i}^{j}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{j} \times F_{i}^{j} \\ \text{()used dummy varialble concept} 
\end{split} 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i tried both of your code and found many mistake and not the effective technique.In your first code i used \; like 10-15 to get actual spacing which is i think lame.the 2nd one is nice and would see and try to implement it.But still the problem is not solved?